# Error creating SPSite using powershell

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, spsite

I am trying to create a web application `"http://Intranet"` and a site collection `"http://Intranet"` on SharePoint 2013 foundation farm. Here is my code

```
$sp = New-SPAuthenticationProvider
$web = New-SPWebApplication -Name "Intranet Home" `
                 -Port 80 `
                 -Url "http://Intranet" `
                 -ApplicationPool "Intranet App Pool" `
                 -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount "mars\svc_intranetapppool") `
                 -AuthenticationProvider $sp

$web = Get-SPWebApplication "http://Intranet"
# Create a New Site at the Base of the Web App
New-SPSite "http://Intranet"  -OwnerAlias "mars\aaronp" `
                        -Name "Intranet Sites" `
                        -HostHeaderWebApplication $web `
                        -Template "STS#0"
```

The error I get is

```
New-SPSite : The URL "http://Intranet" is in use as an alternate access URL or as the URL of a host header site.  
Please choose a different URL and try again.
At line:3 char:1
   + New-SPSite http://Intranet  -OwnerAlias "mars\aaronp" `
   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...SPCmdletNewSite:SPCmdletNewSite) [New-SPSite], ArgumentException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletNewSite
```

How does one create a site collection at the root of the web-app.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a **Root Site Collection** a the top level of your *Web application* you should not use the parameter: **-HostHeaderWebApplication** in the [New-SPSite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607937%28v=office.15%29.aspx) command.

This site collection must have the same *URL* as the *Web application*. Currently, SharePoint prevents the creation of a host-named site collection with the same *URL* as a *Web application*.

> Therefore, the **root site collection** is created as a path-based
>   site collection: "/"

```
#The last line from the code written by Joesoc above should be:
New-SPSite "http://Intranet" -OwnerAlias "mars\aaronp" -Name "Intranet Sites" -Template "STS#0"

#Without "-HostHeaderWebApplication $web `"
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Thumbs up!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you already have a site named that, or an Alternate Access Mapping that points to that URL.

Try and type

```
Get-SPSite -Limit All
```

in a PowerShell session and look for a site called `http://Intranet`

If the URL does not show up, try checking for AAA's:

```
Get-SPAlternateURL
```

to see if you have defined the URL there

Answer (score 0):

```
# SharePoint cmdlets
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
# Set variables
$WebAppName = "Contoso Sharepoint1"
$WebAppHostHeader = "sharepoint1.contoso.com"
$WebAppPort = 80
$WebAppAppPool = "SharePoint1AppPool"
# This User has to be a Sharepoint Manager Account
$WebAppAppPoolAccount = "contoso\sp_serviceuser"
$WebAppDatabaseName = "Sharepoint1"
$WebAppDatabaseServer = "SQLServer\InstanceName"
$SiteCollectionName = "Homepage"
$SiteCollectionURL = ("http://" + $WebAppHostHeader)
$SiteCollectionTemplate = "STS#0"
$SiteCollectionLanguage = 1033
$SiteCollectionOwner = "contoso\UserName"

# Create a new Sharepoint WebApplication
New-SPWebApplication -Name $WebAppName -Port $WebAppPort -HostHeader $WebAppHostHeader -URL ("http://" + $WebAppHostHeader) -ApplicationPool $WebAppAppPool -ApplicationPoolAccount (Get-SPManagedAccount $WebAppAppPoolAccount) -DatabaseName $WebAppDatabaseName -DatabaseServer $WebAppDatabaseServer

# Create a new Sharepoint Site Collection
New-SPSite -URL $SiteCollectionURL -OwnerAlias $SiteCollectionOwner -Language $SiteCollectionLanguage -Template $SiteCollectionTemplate -Name $SiteCollectionName`enter code here`
```